# Re-export bundled React for other Webpack bundles

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

In my real-world application, I have a Webpack bundle that includes the main Javascript application and multiple dependencies. Additionally, I have some optional Webpack bundles with Javascript code that use the same dependencies as the main Webpack bundle. How can I re-export bundled dependencies from my main Webpack bundle for other bundles?

**Minimal example project**

[Download](https://gofile.io/?c=62aHuc)

***My app***

myapp/index.html

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="optional"></div>
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="../mylib/dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

myapp/app.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello from App!"), document.getElementById("root"));
console.log("My application is loaded");
```

myapp/package.json

```
{
    "name": "myapp",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^14.29.6",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
    }
}
```

myapp/webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './app.js',
    output: { filename: 'bundle.js' }
};
```

***My optional library***

mylib/lib.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello from Library!"), document.getElementById("optional"));
console.log("My optional library is loaded");
```

mylib/package.json

```
{
    "name": "mylib",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.6"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "webpack": "^14.29.6",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.0"
    }
}
```

mylib/webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './lib.js',
    output: { filename: 'bundle.js' },
    externals: { 'react': 'React', 'react-dom': 'ReactDOM' }
};
```

When I open `myapp/index.html`, I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: React is not defined` from the library. However, the app itself works and prints `Hello from App!`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution by using Webpack's [DllPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/#dllplugin) and [DllReferencePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/#dllreferenceplugin).

**My changes:**

myapp/index.html

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="optional"></div>
    <script src="./dist/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="../mylib/dist/bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

mylib/webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = [
    {
        name: 'vendor',
        entry: ['react', 'react-dom'],
        output: { filename: 'vendor.js', library: 'vendor' },
        plugins: [new webpack.DllPlugin({ name: 'vendor', path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/manifest.json') })]
    },
    {
        entry: './app.js',
        output: { filename: 'bundle.js' },
        dependencies: ['vendor'],
        plugins: [new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({ manifest: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist/manifest.json') })]
    }
];
```

mylib/webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
    entry: './lib.js',
    output: { filename: 'bundle.js' },
    plugins: [new webpack.DllReferencePlugin({ manifest: path.resolve(__dirname, '../myapp/dist/manifest.json'), name: 'vendor' })]
};
```